# Physic Spring Joint Worked Unexpectedly

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm quite new to Sprite Builder. I'm trying  [Clone Angry Birds with SpriteBuilder > Add Physics using Chipmunk, Part 1](https://www.makegameswith.us/tutorials/getting-started-with-spritebuilder/spritebuilder-physics/). Now I encountered a weird problem.

According to the code, the restLength of spring that joins catapult arm and the square shouldn't be able to be stretched. The square is a invisible CCNode.

`_mouseJoint = [CCPhysicsJoint connectedSpringJointWithBodyA:_mouseJointNode.physicsBody bodyB:_catapultArm.physicsBody anchorA:ccp(0, 0) anchorB:ccp(14, 150) restLength:0.f stiffness:3000.f damping:150.f];`

Here's my spring(Sorry I don't know how to make a screenshot while dragging the mouse):
[image: My Spring]

And here's what it should look like:
[image: Should Be]

It seems the spring in the tutorial can't be stretched, and I didn't see this invisible CCNode in the expected result.

Is this because of the value of anchorB? Actually I don't think so.

All the suggestions will be appreciated. =)

Comment: just fyi rest length as well as min/max distance of distance joints are not absolute limits that can not be exceeded. If you need an absolute length/distance you can do so only with collisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I got why. I should set the invisible CCNode to Circle and its corner to 0. Also, I should set it to "static"